# How to write dead notes in Abjad?

Tags: python, lilypond

I've taken this example [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/special-note-heads.html) from the Lily Pond docs. [This is expected output.](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/ab/lily-633320d1.png)
This is my Python script.

```
import abjad
notes = r"c''4 b \xNote { e f } c b < g \xNote c f > b"
voice_1 = abjad.Voice(notes)
staff = abjad.Staff([voice_1])
abjad.show(staff)
```

Console is throwing "Exception: LilyPondParser can not emulate music function: \xNote.". Any idea why this is happening? Or how to do this correctly?

The attached image shows expected output. Instead I'm getting an "LilyPondParser can not emulate music function: \xNote" error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about abjad, but the correct syntax is \xNotesOn and \xNotesOff, not just \xNotes.

Comment: Changing notes to 
`notes = r"c''4 b \xNotesOn  e f  c b g \xNotesOff c f b"`
Does get rid of the error. But gives the output without dead note heads. Identical to the output of
`notes = r"c''4 b  e f  c b g c f b"`